# How to to select specific checkboxes in System Preferences?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to select the third checkbox of the Keyboard menu item and tab to change the basic fn key function with one run of the script. The rest of the code appears to work fine, but I just recently started trying to code at all so I have no idea.

Here is my current code:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell (click checkbox 3 of tab group 1)
            delay 2
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

And here is the error message:

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1." number -1728 from tab group 1
```

It looks like I'm just not defining it correctly, but I can't find out how to. Any help is appreciated!

Also, this is not needed but would it be possible to run the script without visibly opening the System Preferences application?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? What's the title of the checkbox your are trying to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested under **macOS Catalina** and clicks the **Turn keyboard backlight off after** *checkbox* at: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard**

As coded, it does the following:

- Checks to see if **System Preferences** is running and if it is, it closes it so as to not have to see the **UI** flashing thru the different *panes*.
- If **System Preferences** is not running it opens to the target *anchor/pane* without showing the **UI**.
- Clicks the target *checkbox*.
- Closes **System Preferences**

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane id ¬
        "com.apple.preference.keyboard"

tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until (exists checkbox 3 of tab group 1)
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        click checkbox 3 of tab group 1
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling*, does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>