# MACOS - How to create a on/off shortcut for Remote Login?

Tags: applescript

(I have asked this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/macapps/comments/vrgyhi/is_there_an_app_or_a_somekind_of_way_to_make_a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) got couple of suggestions but they are not ideal so I though I might try my luck here)

I want to have either Menu bar toggle (like BT or WIFI) or keyboard shortcut [⌘+F12] that toggles Remote_Login on/off in the background without opening the system preferences window...
[Remote Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbySQ.png)
[Idea of perfect solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urnaX.png)

I am currently using or Keysmith macro that:
opens system preferences > sharing > clicks coordinates of the box next to Remote Login > quit
(but its not ideal because it shows the window while doing it)

Maybe there would be a way to modify this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139354/how-to-to-select-specific-checkboxes-in-system-preferences) (1st solution) into toggling Remote Login

or maybe someone has other suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a kind Redditor I modified the earlier code into this:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    set the current pane to pane id ¬
        "com.apple.preferences.sharing"

tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of row 5 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1)
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        click checkbox 1 of row 5 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```